# Unable to install SQLITE3 on Node 14.4.0 - Windows 10

Tags: node.js, electron, node-sqlite3

I am unable to install sqlite3 on Windows 10.

Node version: 14.4.0

The native bindings are not available. Just wondering if anyone has got it working on the Nodejs 14.4.0 / Windows 10 combination.

Answer (score 0):

sqlite3 should work under Node 14 now (cf. https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/1314).